# Updating Android app every day?

Tags: android, google-play

So I have an android game that I'm developing, and it relies on having a new 'level' or puzzle every day. Right now, I'm thinking about pushing out an update every day to Google Play. It seems like a naive approach, so I'm wondering if anyone has a better suggestion for how I might get new content out every day.

Comment: This is a comment since I'm not exactly sure how to implement it. You'd want to have some sort of database full of puzzles that you could have your app check on load. Just put your new puzzles into that database so they were pushed once a day.

Comment: Yeah, that's not a good approach. No one is going to want to update the app every day.

Comment: Hm. Okay. So what I'm thinking of now is just having all the levels stored somewhere on the web (each level is only an image) and having an 'update' option from the levels menu to check that all levels have been downloaded up until that particular day. The question then  is, should I save to phone storage or the app's cache?

Answer (score 5):

You could upload a new level to a `server` and the phone can automatically check if there is a new level available.

Have a look at [parse](http://www.parse.com), they provide server capabilities for your Android app.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you should try to represent everything in the puzzle as a json string if possible.  You may or may not neeed a local database, but I think you might want to store more than one day each pull and the reason for that is because you cannot count on reliable update every day, so it might be better to grab a few each time.  Just send to the server the last one you successfully installed.  Parse is good but you are handing your data and information over to a third party.  You could just store the puzzle in SharedPreferences. Just make sure that there is a date and unique number for each puzzle.  JSON is the preferred way to get and receive data.  You can implement your own server easily in Jersey as a restful service, but many services these days are written in php or python too.  So you just need one service you will call.  thats it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the json approach, you could have an update endpoint that compares a json file in local storage with the one on your site.  If they're different, grab the new source and return that, otherwise return something like

```
{status:"up to date"}
```

Once you have that working I'd throw the 'source' into redis or memcache and have your update endpoint switch between the key you're reading from and the key your update script would be writing to.

```
var active = 0;
var cache = new Array();
var cache[0] = new Buffer();
var cache[1] = new Buffer();

function ReadActive() {
  return cache[active];
}

function WriteToMirror(newValue) {
  cache[1-active] = newValue;
  active = 1 - active;
}

function UpdateStatus(currentValue) {
  var cacheValue = cache[active];
  if(cacheValue  === currentValue)
    return {status:"up to date"};

  return cacheValue;
}
```